# php json readable format

Tags: php, json, decode

Below is my JSON format string:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:2:"id";s:4:"2086";s:12:"variation_id";s:4:"2091";s:4:"name";s:10:"VELCRO BIB";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:9:"item_meta";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:"meta_name";s:4:"Size";s:10:"meta_value";s:10:"0-3 MONTHS";}i:1;a:2:{s:9:"meta_name";s:5:"Color";s:10:"meta_value";s:6:"BEIGE1";}}s:13:"line_subtotal";s:3:"108";s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";s:1:"0";s:10:"line_total";s:3:"108";s:8:"line_tax";s:1:"0";s:9:"tax_class";s:0:"";}}
```

How can i convert it to readable format or in php array format?

I'm using `json_decode` function however it doesn't return anything.

Earliest help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't [JSON](http://www.json.org/)? You'll probably have to write a decoder yourself for this format.

Comment: That looks like serialized PHP.

Comment: oh, thanks for all yr quick answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a serialized php value, not JSON. use [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert it back to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

This string is malformed. `json_decode` is correct. You have to make a correct JSON string and then it should work. If you want to know how a correct JSON string has to be, look at this site: http://www.json.org/